# A heuristic function for 3 Water Jug

Tags: artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, heuristics

I've question to ask you guys.

I'm a newbie in Artificial Intelligence. I want to solve water jug problem(3 jugs - 3 lt, 5lt, 9lt - Trying to get 7lt) using A* search.

I need a heuristic function to implement the solution, but I can't find a good heuristic f(n) so that the algorithm will find the least steps to the solution.

Comment: I also took an AI course in college, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried a function define as h(n) = (sum of goal state's jugs(n) - sum of initial state(n)) / 2.. I could not succeed.

Comment: I meant to flag this as a close for exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806880/water-jug-problem-in-die-hard-3-into-a-graph

Comment: The bigger question is do you know how to solve this problem without using a heuristic?

Comment: Yes, I solved the question using both DFS and BFS.

Comment: Well if you solved it using those two then A* is trivial to implement.  Why don't you post your DFS and BFS code and tell us where you are falling down based on that?

Comment: I have'nt started to implement the code, because I have not found a heuristic function yet. Just need advice for the function.

Comment: I understand that you need advice, however this is clearly a homework assignment.  You need to provide us with things you have written and give clear and concise areas where you are struggling.  I.E. Post your DFS + BFS code, explain why you can't get it to work as A* and we can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given your parameters the non-heuristic way of solving this problem is:

```
0) Fill the 9 liter jug  
1) Pour the 9 liter jug into the 5 liter jug, this leaves 4 liters in the 9 liter  
2) Fill the 3 liter jug  
3) Pour the 3 liter jug into the 9 liter jug and the problem is solved
```

So looking at this you will have a graph that has nodes that can be in one of two states:  `Pour` or `Fill` .  You then assign to each node a weight that represents the amount of liquid you will get from it, `1,2,3,etc` .  There should be no division involved, you just need to make it "expensive" to use specific operations.

Comment: so you say use a function like this one?

f(n) = sum of the amaount of liquid in a state
(Ex: for(2,3,5 = 2 + 3 + 5 = 10) + 
operation amount(Ex: pour = 1, Fill = 1, Empty = 6)

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim it would be something along those lines yes, where the pour,fill, and empty operations are assigned a value or weight.  What the best values for those parameters are is beyond me at the moment especially with dynamic inputs.